# Swift: Question on Generic Functions and Associated Types

Tags: swift, generics, associated-types

Say, I have a protocol with an associated type:

```swift
protocol Model {
    associatedtype ModelType
}
```

And there's a generic struct conforming to this protocol:

```swift
struct Implementation<T>: Model {
    typealias ModelType = T
}
```

Now, I want to add an instance method to this struct accepting and returning a value of the abstract `Model` type:

```swift
struct Implementation<T>: Model {
    typealias ModelType = T
    func test<M: Model>(model: M) -> M {
        return model
    }
}
```

This compiles without errors. I want to go further and make sure that both the `model` parameter and the return value of the `test(model:)` method have the same associated `ModelType` as the `Implementation` instance this method is called on:

```swift
struct Implementation<T>: Model {
    typealias ModelType = T
    func test<M: Model>(model: M) -> M where M.ModelType == T {
        return model
    }
}
```

This compiles without errors, and it works as expected. If there's a second type conforming to `Model`…

```swift
struct Alternative<T>: Model {
    typealias ModelType = T
}
```

…, I can pass an instance of this type to the `test(model:)` method only if it has the same associated `ModelType`. That is, the following code compiles…

```swift
let implementation = Implementation<Int>()
let alternativeA = Alternative<Int>()
_ = implementation.test(model: alternativeA)
```

…, whereas the following code:

```swift
let implementation = Implementation<Int>()
let alternativeB = Alternative<String>()
_ = implementation.test(model: alternativeB)
```

… fails to compile with an error saying,

> Instance method 'test(model:)' requires the types 'Int' and 'Alternative<String>.ModelType' (aka 'String') be equivalent

Now, under some condition, the `test(model:)` method should return `self`. If I change it to (always) return `self`, however…

```swift
struct Implementation<T>: Model {
    typealias ModelType = T
    func test<M: Model>(model: M) -> M where M.ModelType == T {
        return self
    }
}
```

…, I'll get an error saying,

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'Implementation<T>' to return type 'M'

This is confusing, as, clearly, the type of `self` should match all given constraints. (Or doesn't it?)

The error is, in fact, unrelated to the `where` clause. If I drop it…

```swift
struct Implementation<T>: Model {
    typealias ModelType = T
    func test<M: Model>(model: M) -> M {
        return self
    }
}
```

…, the error will persist:

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'Implementation<T>' to return type 'M'

Why am I getting this error, and how can I return `self` from this method?

(I'm using Swift 5.3.2 by the way in case this matters.)

Comment: But Implementation<T> and M are two completely different types so how would you expect this to work? I also find the example code hardtop understand since T is never used by any of the generic types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error, because indeed `self` does not match all given constraints. By stating `func test<M: Model>(model: M) -> M where M.ModelType == T` you only say that this type `M` (which is only exists in the context of a call to your `test` function) is to be a `Model`, which's `ModelType` is the same as the `ModelType` of `self`. That does not mean, however, that `Self` and `M` are equivalent.

A little example using your types from above:

Assuming `self` is an instance of `Implementation<Int>`. In the context of a call to `test(model:)`, `M` could be either of `Implementation<Int>` or `Alternative<Int>`. Returning `self` wouldn't be a problem in the first case, as both instances have the same type. However, in the second case you could assign an `Implementation<Int>` to an `Alternative<Int>`.

```
var a = Alternative<Int>()
let x = Implementation<Int>()
// This would assign something of type `Implementation<Int>` to a variable that
// may only contain `Alternative<Int>`.
var a = x.test(model: a)
```

I am sure there is a method to do what you want to achieve in Swift, but the solution totally depends on what that is.

Answer (score 1):

Generic functions always try to infer type from the context and at compile time

```swift
// func test<M: Model>(_ model: M) -> M
test(Alternative<Int>())
```

is treated as concrete type function

```swift
func test(_ model: Alternative<Int>) -> Alternative<Int>
```

so u cant do

```swift
struct Implementation<T>: Model {
    typealias ModelType = T
    func test(_ model: Alternative<Int>) -> Alternative<Int> {
        return self // Implementation<T>, type mismatch
    }
}
```

Also if you using a generic constraint for your generic function within a type

```swift
struct Implementation<T>: Model {
    typealias ModelType = T
    func test<M: Model>(_ model: M) -> M where M.ModelType == T {
        return model
    }
}
```

For `Implementation<Int>` translated into something like

```swift
extension Implementation where T == Int {
    func test<M: Model>(_ model: M) -> M where M.ModelType == Int {
        return model
    }
}
```

The constraint prevents you from calling

```swift
Implementation<Int>().test(Alternative<String>())
```

Maybe this proposal will let you fix the issue, but I think it will still be impossible, because this case cannot be resolved in compile time. [Proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0309-unlock-existential-types-for-all-protocols.md)

I'm not sure if you really want to return self or model from your method, maybe it's better to pass your model as an `inout` parameter.
If you still want to return self you may do something like this

```swift
struct Implementation<T>: Model {
    typealias ModelType = T
    func test<M: Model>(_ model: M) -> Self where M.ModelType == T {
        return self
    }
}
```

You may overload this method to let compiler decide (from the context) what to use

```swift
struct Implementation<T>: Model {
    typealias ModelType = T
    func test<M: Model>(_ model: M) -> Self where M.ModelType == T {
        return self
    }

    func test<M: Model>(_ model: M) -> T where M.ModelType == T {
        return model
    }
}
```

But it may cause some type inference issues if `M == Self`

Btw you already creating an existential for your protocol by making a protocol witness

[Protocol wintesses](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BVkbWXcFS4)

Also I'm not sure if you really need to create a few witness types for your `Model` protocol, maybe you can generalize your work just using `Implementation<T>` extensions with generic constraints